# Simple string replace in xml

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string that contains a fair bit of XML, it's actually xml that describes a word document(document.xml). I want to simply replace a part of the string with an empty string effectivally removing it from the string. This sounds straight forward but I'm not getting the result I expect.

Here is what some of the XML looks like, this is just the first 10 lines:

```
<w:body xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:p w:rsidR="00CB3A3E" w:rsidP="00257CF7" w:rsidRDefault="008C1E91">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading-Title" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>References</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sdt>
```

As I said this is in a string. I simply try to replace `<w:t>References</w:t>` with an empty string. I am doing it like so:

```
//xmlBody is the string that is holding the xml
xmlBody.Replace("<w:t>References</w:t>", " ");
```

This is not working, the string is unaltered when I do this. What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks much!

Comment: Please try to use proper XML objects to manipulate XML. First you will not produce invalud XML this way and second you'll avoid asking "how to parse/search XML with regular expressions" when you find that <w:t> could be on separeate lines from text or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xmlBody = xmlBody.Replace("<w:t>References</w:t>", "");
```

The Replace function doesn't change the source string; it returns a new string with the changes made. In fact, C# strings cannot be changed. If you check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx), it says that they're immutable.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, string is not mutable - once created, it cannot be changed. `Replace` returns a new instance of string. Therefore, you need to catch its return value:

```
xmlBody = xmlBody.Replace("<w:t>References</w:t>", " ");
```

As a sidenote, it is not considered a good practice to parse XML-based strings with regular expressions, because it's too fragile. Consider using `XDocument` or some such to remove elements you are after.

Answer (score 2):

string.replace returns a new string, it doesn't change the original string

try

```
xmlBody = xmlBody.Replace("<w:t>References</w:t>", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace isn't an inline replacement... it returns a new string with the replacement made.